# How to match with or without a given letter

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a string like `'r"abc"'` or `'"abc"'` I thought I would do `'[r|.]"[\w]+"'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `?` to mean optional.

```
'r?"\\w+"'
```

Example usage:

```
>>> re.match('r?"\\w+"', 'r"abc"')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002A57440>
>>> re.match('r?"\\w+"', '"abc"')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000029FDAC0>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'r?"\w+"'
```

should do, you match `r` prefix optionally. Also square brackets around a `\w` are not needed: it's a single character!